# Are these two representations of MAPE equal and correct?

Tags: notation, error-function

Just came across two equations that claim to represent the Mean Absolute Percentage Error.

One is as follows ([Source](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#mean-absolute-percentage-error))

$$
\mathrm{MAPE}\left(y,\hat{y}\right)=\frac{1}{n_{\mathrm{samples}}}\sum_{i=0}^{n_{\mathrm{samples}}-1}\frac{\left|y_i-\widehat{y_i}\right|}{max\left(\epsilon,\left|y_i\right|\right)}
$$

and the other one, from `Caiado, J. (2011). Métodos de Previsão em Gestão-Com Aplicações em Excel. Edições Sílabo, Lisboa`, as follows

$$
\mathrm{MAPE}=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{t=1}^{m}\left|\frac{y_t-{P_t}}{y_t}\right|\times100
$$

By looking at both of them, and knowing that MAPE is a percentage, I wonder if the output of the first equation is a percentage even though `x100` is not explicit?

Do both of the functions represent the same thing, in this case, the MAPE?

Comment: The significant difference is that the latter risks dividing by zero. Someone in the field might know which formula is more common, and whether writing the 100 in explicitly is common or not.